# Can't run QML app with C++ plugin (cmake) in emulator

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, ubuntu-emulator

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. I created a project QML app with C++ plugin (cmake), and then I want to start it.
In desktop it's running fine.
When I tried to start it in emulator I got:

```
Framework "ubuntu-sdk-15.04" not present on system
```

The whole output is:

```
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Sdk-Launcher> Executing:     /tmp/delete2.username_0.1_armhf.click
Sdk-Launcher> Force Install: False
Sdk-Launcher> Skip Uninstall:False
Sdk-Launcher> Launcher PID: 19987
Sdk-Launcher> Installing application .....
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Transaction:    Installing files
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Waiting for authentication
Status:     Waiting in queue
Status:     Starting
Status:     Finished
Results:
Fatal error: /tmp/delete2.username_0.1_armhf.click failed to install.
WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /tmp/delete2.username_0.1_armhf.click: Framework "ubuntu-sdk-15.04" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)

Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed
```

When I add --force-missing-framework option to the Project/Build settings/CMake arguments ( not sure if it was the right place ) , I got :

-1: error: No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in building, but that your emulator doesn't have the 15.04 framework on it.  You might try downloading a newer emulator image, but I'm not sure if the 15.04 framework has made it onto them yet.

The `--force-missing-framework` option is meant for the install command running on the emulator, not your build command.  If you copy your click package over to the emulator, you may be able to install it with the command `sudo click install --force-missing-framework --user=$USER *.click`.  (I believe this method is deprecated in favor of using `pkcon`, but that doesn't seem to have this option.)

But before you go through any of this trouble, do you *need* the newest framework?  (Note that, if you're using qmake, you do need 15.04.  In that case, ignore the following.)  For right now, your best bet may be to temporarily move your project to the 14.10 framework.

Comment: when using different 14.10 emulator I got : file:///opt/click.ubuntu.com/delete2.username/0.1/share/qml/delete2/delete2.qml:3 plugin cannot be loaded for module "Delete2": The plugin '/opt/click.ubuntu.com/delete2.username/0.1/lib/i386-linux-gnu/Delete2/libDelete2backend.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.4.1) [release]

Comment: You'll need to compile your project in a 14.10 chroot, in order to match the Qt version in 14.10 (5.2, I believe, but don't quote me on that).  Of course, this will only work if you don't use any Qt features introduced after 5.2.  Otherwise, you do need the newest framework.

Comment: always problems :
.......................... Scanning dependencies of target delete2.desktop
[ 83%] Merging translations into delete2.desktop
po/CMakeFiles/delete2.desktop.dir/build.make:49: recipe for target 'po/CMakeFiles/delete2.desktop' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:374: recipe for target 'po/CMakeFiles/delete2.desktop.dir/all' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386/bin/sh: 1: /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-i386/usr/bin/intltool-merge: not found

Comment: I'd try installing inittool in your chroot.  There's an additional constraint I just learned: qmake requires the 15.04 framework.  Don't know if that's relevant to you, but I've edited my answer.